# How to migrate Wordpress between Compute Engine instances

Tags: wordpress, migration, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have recently created a very *small* **Google Compute Engine** instance, naively thinking it's one of those easily scalable things Google people keep raving about.
I used the quick deployment feature of Wordpress and it all installed itself nicely, so I started configuring  and adding data etc.

However, I then found out that I can't scale an existing instance (i.e. it won't allow me to change the instance type to a bigger one. I don't get why not, but there you go.), so it looks like I need to find a way to migrate my Wordpress installation to a new instance.

Will I simply be able to create a new instance and point it at the persistent disk my small instance currently uses, et voila, Bob's your uncle?

Or do I need to manually get the files and MySql data off the first instance and re-import into an empty new instance?
What's the easiest way?

Any advise or helpful links would be appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S.: Btw, should I try to use the Google Cloud SQL store instead of a local MySql installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to upgrade your VM:

1. access the VM's settings in the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) (your project -> Compute -> Compute Engine -> VM instances -> click on the VM's name)
2. Scroll down to the "Disks" section, and un-check "Delete boot disk when instance is deleted"
3. Delete the VM in question. Take note that the disk, named after the instance, will remain.
4. Create a new VM, selecting "Existing disk" under Boot disk - Boot source. In the next box down, select the disk from point 3 above, as well as a bigger machine type.

The resulting new instance will use the existing disk from the old one, with improved hardware / performance.

As for using [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) in lieu of a VM-installed database, it's perfectly feasible, and allows to adjust the Cloud SQL instance to match your actual use. A few consideration when setting up this kind of instance:

- [limit the IPs allowed to connect](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control#appaccess) to your Cloud SQL instance to your frontend's IP, and perhaps the workstation's IP or subnet from which you maintain the database out of.
- [configure Cloud SQL to use SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/instances#ssl).

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Thank you for the step-by-step instructions and the tips on the cloud SQL! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sammy's answer covers the important stuff I just wanted to clarify how your files are arranged on the two disks that are attached to your instance:

The data disk contains /var/www/ which is all of the wordpress files.  It's mounted on the instance at /wordpress

The boot disk contains everything else, including the MySQL database that was created for the Wordpress installation.

Comment: When you attach an additional disk to a VM, you can select whether it ought to be created from an existing image, use an existing disk, or create a new, blank disk. Once attached, and taking the case of a secondary, empty disk, it behaves like any other block device. Once partitioned with your favourite tools, the new partition can be mounted anywhere you wish in the file system...

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't think there was anything on the second disk. I only added it because the boot disk had only 10GB and I will eventually need more.